# Calculating Concurrency of Jobs in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to calculate the concurrency of jobs in excel. I have the start time and end time of jobs.

In the image below I want a result of 3 as that is the maximum concurrency.

[image]

I have tried numerous COUNTIFS formulas but not getting the correct result

[image]

Sample of the data

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a formula you tried, what the results of the formula were, and why the results were incorrect?

Comment: I have added another image to the description. The red line is the job I want to calculate concurrency for. There are many of these jobs. Unfortunately this counts too many jobs as some jobs are contained within job 'red' but are not concurrent with each other

Comment: Is it correct that, judging by your calculations link, you have nearly a million rows of data? We need to see a sample of your data to get a better picture of it.

Comment: I have added a picture of the data in the table in the post

Comment: Could you provide a bigger picture? as @TomSharpe said, it looks like you have a million rows of data. what is the row number?

Comment: Yes there is approximately 1 million rows of data. which look the same as the picture. The data is over a period of approximately 1.5 years. Some jobs last for a few days, other jobs are 1 second in duration.

Comment: The trouble is that, with simple solutions, this looks like an O(n^2) problem. So with 10^6 rows of data you're looking at 10^12 operations which looks prohibitive. There is a more efficient approach here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-point-where-maximum-intervals-overlap/ with a sample Java solution which could be re-written in VBA...

Comment: Step 1: Add a pair of values to a list, once for every interval, containing the values of `(start, +1)`. Then add a pair of values to the same list, once for every interval, containing the values of `(end, -1)`. Step 2: Sort this list according to the first value in each pair. Step 3: Run through the list in sequential order keeping a running tally of the sum of the second value in each pair. The maximum value you reach is the maximum parallelism. This solution is O(N log N) due to the sorting.

Comment: This is essentially the same approach used here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-point-where-maximum-intervals-overlap/ only they implement it using a separate list for start and end values and merging the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how it looks in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UsingArrayList()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim FirstRow, LastRow As Long
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    Dim arrival As Object, departure As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim guests_in As Long, max_guests As Long, time As Double

    Set arrival = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set departure = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With sht
    ' Copy ranges into arrival and departure arrays
    FirstRow = 2
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        arrival.Add (.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        departure.Add (.Cells(i, 2).Value)
    Next i
    End With

 ' Sort arrival and departure arrays
    arrival.Sort
    departure.Sort

    ' guests_in indicates number of guests at a time
    guests_in = 1
    max_guests = 1
    time = arrival.Item(0)
    i = 1
    j = 0
    n = arrival.Count

    ' Similar to merge in merge sort to process
    ' all events in sorted order
    While (i < n And j < n)

        ' If next event in sorted order is arrival,
        ' increment count of guests
        If (arrival.Item(i) <= departure.Item(j)) Then

            guests_in = guests_in + 1

            ' Update max_guests if needed
            If (guests_in > max_guests) Then

                max_guests = guests_in
                time = arrival.Item(i)
            End If
            i = i + 1 'increment index of arrival array

        Else ' If event is departure, decrement count
         ' of guests.
            guests_in = guests_in - 1
            j = j + 1
        End If

    Wend


Debug.Print ("Max concurrency=" & max_guests)
Debug.Print ("at time " & time)
Debug.Print ("at time " & Application.Text(time, "hh:mm:ss"))
End Sub
```

If I run it on the test data provided [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-point-where-maximum-intervals-overlap/) I get the expected answer of 3 for the concurrency at 5 o'clock.

If I run it on your sample of 9 rows of data, I get a concurrency of 9 at 7:14:41 - because all of the time periods in the sample overlap.

I have tried running it on a full column of data, and it takes 2-3 minutes.